# Problema con ciertos comandos: "no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable"

Tags: linux, línea-de-comandos

Tenemos un problema con putty(Linux), entramos con el servidor en putty y parece que todo esta bien, si ejecutamos comandos como *cd* o *mkdir* los realiza, en cambio si ejecutamos otros básicos como *ls* o *cat* nos dice que no existen.

Respuesta al intentar ejecutar ls:

```
"ls" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Creamos el servidor desde freeSSHd y utilizamos a putty como cliente.
El problema no puede estar en el archivo es un tema de comandos.

Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo os agradecemos la ayuda.

Gracias.

Comment: Si te sirve dir y no ls, significa que no estas usando Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Estás seguro de que estás en una línea de comandos de Linux?
Por lo que cuentas, parece que estás en un `cmd` de Windows. Prueba a hacer un comando `dir` (equivalente de `ls` en Windows) y coméntanos tu resultado. Investigando por Internet es lo único que he encontrado.

Comment: Según me dijeron en clase sí pero me ha funcionado dir. Sabes donde puedo encontrar comandos equivalentes para poder trabajar hasta que me den usa solución. Muchas gracias

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, recuerda que las preguntas se realizan como comentarios, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: [Aquí](https://ftp.kh.edu.tw/Linux/Redhat/en_6.2/doc/gsg/ch-doslinux.htm) puedes encontrar una lista con comandos equivalentes. La columna MS-DOS es la que necesitas y a la derecha aparece la equivalencia en Linux.

Comment: Buenas Jorge, sí lo sé, pero aún no tenía 50 de reputación y no podía hacer comentarios así. Un saludo

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!